# Using a Makefile with C

Tags: c, makefile

So I have three files:

```
jarvismarch.c (includes "jarvismarchtools.h")
jarvismarchtools.c
jarvismarchtools.h
```

I would like to use a `makefile` to compile the aforementioned files. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical minimal makefile looks like this:

```
OBJ = jarvismarch.o jarvismarchtools.o

all: $(OBJ)
        $(CC) -o jarvismarch $(OBJ)
```

Taking the comment of [asveikau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182748/asveikau) into account and adding a clean target it becomes:

```
OBJ = jarvismarch.o jarvismarchtools.o
BIN = jarvismarch

CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -ansi

all: $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o @ $(OBJ)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) $(BIN)
```

(Windows users need to use `.obj` instead of `.o`)

I strongly recommend against using make. It might be simple at first, but once your project grows I highly recommend a more complete build tool like [SCons](http://www.scons.org/), [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) or [Boost.Build](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/).

Comment: I would actually make `all` depend on `jarvismarch` and have a new `jarvismarch: $(OBJ)` target then use `-o @` instead of `-o jarvismarch`.

Comment: @asveikau Agreed. I also added a clean target and put the name of the binary in a BIN variable. Everything from there is just adding various CFLAGS, LIBS, etc. variables.

Comment: I just added some CFLAGS to the Makefile example: Typically you want to use at least `-Wall`, `-pedantic` and `-ansi`. (Those depend on the compiler you are using. The listed flags are for GCC)

Comment: The big trouble with the last suggestions is that `make` (at least some half-broken version) is available anywhere, the other build tools mentioned are rather exotic and anything but in common use. And discussions I've seen show that they are simpler for some tasks while making other common tasks impossible or hard.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are trying to build jarvismarch.exe:

```
jarvismarch.exe : jarvismarch.o jarvismarchtools.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

The leading whitespace on the second line needs to be a TAB character.